# Relationship between object.create and prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have two chunks of code and they seem to work the same. The only difference between the two is one has Object.create() and the other does not. Am I missing some potential consequence of not using it?

First Chunk, does not use Object.create:

```js
function Rectangle(width, height) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
}

Rectangle.prototype.area = function() {
  return this.width * this.height;
};

function Square(side) {
  Rectangle.call(this, side, side);
}

Square.prototype = Rectangle.prototype;

Square.prototype.constructor = Square;

var sq = new Square(5);
console.log(sq.area())
```

Second Chunk, uses Object.create:

```js
function Rectangle(width, height) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
}

Rectangle.prototype.area = function() {
  return this.width * this.height;
};

function Square(side) {
  Rectangle.call(this, side, side);
}

Square.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype);

Square.prototype.constructor = Square;

var sq = new Square(5);
console.log(sq.area())
```

Comment: `Object.create()` *(lowercase `c`)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not the same. With this line, the two constructors' prototypes are the same object.

```
Square.prototype = Rectangle.prototype;
```

This means that any method on a `Square` will also appear on a `Rectangle`. So use `Object.create()` to assign a new object that *inherits from* `Rectangle.prototype`. That way methods will be added to that object, and not to `Rectangle.prototype`.

Comment: if it is possible it will be opposite of what is written in 3rd line.

Comment: @suchit: Not sure what you mean. What will be opposite if what is possible?

Comment: any method on a Rectangle will also appear on a Square.

Comment: @suchit: Right. Any method on a Rectangle will also appear on a Square, and any method on a Square will also appear on a Rectangle. It's two ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: why it will be two way assignment.it looks like normal right to left.

Comment: @suchit: By doing that, both `.prototype` properties are referencing the same object. So any property added to that object will appear on new objects created from both constructors.

Comment: ...here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2xp55qm8/

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to skim the post, I marked information directly related to your example with *italics*.

## Prototypal inheritance

The prototypal inheritance works as follows:

1. Each object `o` has a prototype `o.__proto__`.
2. When you request a property `p` on object `o`, then:

   1. If the object `o` has property `p`, `o[p]` is returned.
   2. Otherwise:

      1. If `o.__proto__ !== null`, then `o.__proto__[p]` is returned.
      2. Otherwise, `undefined` is returned.

This behaviour is recursive, creating a so-called [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). See the example code below:

```
var o1 = { a: 1 },
    o2 = { b: 2 },
    o3 = { c: 3 };
o2.__proto__ = o1;
o3.__proto__ = o2;
o3.a + o3.b + o3.c == 6;   // true
```

This is basically all there is to prototypes. It ought to be noted that `__proto__` is a [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) way of accessing the prototype. ECMAScript provides three other (standard) ways:

- the `prototype` property of functions,
- the `Object.create()` method,
- the `Object.getPrototypeOf()` and `Object.setPrototypeOf()` methods.

Let us now look at these.

### The `prototype` property of functions

#### The basics

Up to ECMAScript 5, the `prototype` property of functions was the only way to work with prototypes. It works as follows:

1. Each function `f` has a `prototype` property.
2. When `new f(arg1, arg2, ..., argN)` is invoked, then:

   1. An empty new object `o` is created, where `o.__proto__ == f.prototype`.
   2. The function `f` is invoked with arguments `arg1, arg2, ..., argN` in the context of `o`.
   3. If the function `f` doesn't return any value, then `o` is returned.

This behaviour basically mimics classical inheritance. You fill the `f.prototype` object with methods that objects obtained by calling `new f` will inherit and `f` itself serves as a constructor.

#### The `prototype.constructor` property

As far as constructors are concerned, the `f.prototype` object contains by default a `f.prototype.constructor` property, which equals to `f`. This can be used to find out the object's constructor either by checking out the `constructor` property directly or by using the `instanceof` syntactic sugar:

```
var o = new f;
o.constructor == f;        // true
o instanceof f;            // true
```

*In your first example, you changed the `prototype.constructor` of both `Square` and `Rectangle` to `Square`. Therefore:*

```
var o = new Rectange;
o instanceof Rectangle;    // false
o instanceof Square;       // true
```

*This usually isn't what you want.*

#### Extending the prototypes of built-in objects

Extending the `prototype` object of built-in functions / constructors (`String`, `Array`, `Number`, `RegExp`, ...) can be a useful application of this principle:

```
Array.prototype.last = function() {
  return this[this.length - 1];
};

[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].last();  // 5
```

### The `Object.create()` method

The [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method is a part of the ECMAScript 5 and allows you to create new objects with specified prototypes without having to create constructor functions. This is the initial `__proto__` example code rewritten using the [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method:

```
var o1 = Object.create(null, {
      a: {
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        value: 1
      }
    }), o2 = Object.create(o1, {
      b: {
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        value: 2
      }
    }), o3 = Object.create(o2, {
      c: {
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        value: 3
      }
    });
o3.a + o3.b + o3.c == 6;   // true
```

Setting the object's properties using the second argument of [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) can get quite wordy. If you don't need the flexibility ECMAScript 5 offers (creating immutable properties, properties with setters and getters, ...), you can omit the second argument and fill the object with values as usual:

```
var o1 = Object.create(null);
o1.a = 1;    
var o2 = Object.create(o1);
o2.b = 2;
var o3 = Object.create(o2);
o3.c = 3;
o3.a + o3.b + o3.c == 6;   // true
```

*In your second example, you changed the `prototype` property of `Square` to `Object.create(Rectangle.prototype)` and then set `Square.prototype` to `Rectangle.prototype`. Since the [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method returns an empty object with, you don't override anything in the `Rectangle`'s prototype by assigning to it, so:*

```
var o1 = new Rectange;
var o2 = new Square;
o1 instanceof Rectangle;    // true
o2 instanceof Square;       // true
```

### The `Object.getPrototypeOf()` and `Object.setPrototypeOf()` methods

The [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) and [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) methods are a part of the [ECMAScript 6 draft](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-getprototypeof) and are just a getter and a setter to the `__proto__` attribute. This is the initial `__proto__` example code rewritten using the [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) method:

```
var o1 = { a: 1 },
    o2 = { b: 2 },
    o3 = { c: 3 };
Object.setPrototypeOf(o2, o1);
Object.setPrototypeOf(o3, o2);
o3.a + o3.b + o3.c == 6;   // true
```